# systemd‘s syntax to pass a parameter

Tags: systemd

How can I get the present path as the parameter? And how can I pass this parameter to the ExecStart?

```
[Unit]
Description="xxxxxxx"

[Service]
EnvironmentFile='WORKDIR=/home/aaaa/bbbbb/' #I want to get this path dynamically when I put this in another path.
WorkingDirectory=/home/aaaa/bbbbb
ExecStart=/home/aaaa/bbbbb/server --database:/home/aaaa/bbbbb/cfg.json
ExecStop=/bin/sleep 5
KillMode=process
KillSignal=SIGQUIT
Restart=always
RestartSec=5s
LimitFSIZE=infinity
LimitCPU=infinity
LimitAS=infinity
LimitNOFILE=64000
LimitNPROC=64000
TasksMax=infinity
TasksAccounting=false

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please describe what you are actually trying to achieve, your question looks pretty unclear. Please make the title of your question more specific: “question about” – well, _every_ question here is a question, “the systemd” – systemd does a lot of things… Are you trying to set up a service (just guessing)? Using appropriate [tags](https://askubuntu.com/tags) would also help to get your question answered.

Comment: What do you mean by *"the"* current directory? Each and every process has its own current working directory.

Comment: @AlexP it means my whole backend might not be deployed under /home/aaaa/bbbbb/ this path when i deliver to the customer.so i want to get the current directory dynamically in this xxxx.service that i can make a soft link from /lib/systemd/system to here.

Comment: In what language is your `server` written? Is it a (wrapper-)script? Would be great if it was.

Comment: @PerlDuck it is written by nim,and compiled it to a executable file of binary.

Comment: And is it possible to put a wrapper-script around it? The script could easily determine the current working directory and then start `server` with that parameter.

Comment: @PerlDuck u means i can use a script to get the present path and pass it to the ExecStart?

Comment: No, I meant to pass the current path to `server`, not to `ExecStart`. After re-reading all the comments, the Q, and the A, I think muru's suggestion to use a `%I` template seems what you want.

Comment: @PerlDuck but how can i without re-write the Environment when i deployed the whole file in the another path.i want the Environment  can get the present path automatically.

Comment: muru already wrote it: `systemctl enable my-service@the/customers/custom/path.service` and then `systemctl start my-service@the/customers/custom/path.service`. The `the/customers/custom/path` is inserted into your unit file wherever a `%I` is given.

Comment: @PerlDuck but  i run systemctl --user start myservice@home/aaaa/bbbbb.service just got this message-- Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1):

Systemd doesn't make the working directory accessible via [specifiers](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Specifiers), nor can you use environment variables in setting [`WorkingDirectory`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/242028/70524). You can use environment variables in `ExecStart`, but not for the [command path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48947416/2072269). So, unless you use workarounds, you will have to specify the path at least thrice (note that you want `Environment=`, not `EnvironmentFile=`):

```
Environment='WORKDIR=/home/aaaa/bbbbb'
WorkingDirectory=/home/aaaa/bbbbb
ExecStart=/home/aaaa/bbbbb/server --database:${WORKDIR}/cfg.json
```

Or, wrap your command in `sh` instead:

```
Environment='WORKDIR=/home/aaaa/bbbbb'
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'cd ${WORKDIR}; exec ${WORKDIR}/server --database:${WORKDIR}/cfg.json'
```

(Hopefully your `WORKDIR` doesn't include spaces or other special characters in it.)

Or, if you make the unit a template, you can do:

```
Environment='WORKDIR=/%I'
WorkingDirectory=/%I
ExecStart=/%I/server --database:/%I/cfg.json
```

And do something like:

```
systemctl --user start my-service@home/aaaa/bbbbb.service
```

Note the leading slash `/` before the `%I`. The path to the executable must be absolute, with or without specifiers, so we need to use `/%I`.

Comment: but i need to get the current directory dynamically

Comment: @Jimmy So you are asking how to get the **c**urrent **w**orking **d**irectory from within your `bbbb` script? Look at the `cwd`/`getcwd()` function and/or environment variable `$PWD`.

Comment: my fault,bbbbb also part of the path.i just want to get the current directory  dynamically in this xxxx.service

Comment: @Jimmy get it where? Why is it dynamic?

Comment: cause my whole backend might not be deployed under /home/aaaa/bbbbb/ this path when i deliver to the customer.so i want to get the current directory dynamically in this xxxx.service that i can make a soft link from /lib/systemd/system to here.

Comment: @Jimmy then use templates and provide instructions to your customer to use specifiers as given in the post. Or don't install in a user's home directory.

Comment: @muru when i run systemctl --user start myservice@home/aaaa/bbbbb.service just got this message-- Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory

Comment: @muru when i run systemctl --user start myservice@home/aaaa/bbbbb/myservice.service,still got the same message